# Logical positivism on religious language

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-religion, logical-positivism

I was searching for an essay on logical positivists’ view of religious language but I can't seem to find any good one.
Can someone point out to me some links related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with Alexander Bryan Johnson's "[A Treatise On Language](https://ia600708.us.archive.org/0/items/treatiseonlangua00john/treatiseonlangua00john.pdf)"

And there's Alfred Jules "[Freddie](http://www.quirkality.com/index.php/the-stories/20-the-strange-tale-of-a-j-ayer-naomi-campbell-and-mike-tyson)" Ayer's "[Language, Truth and Logic](http://s-f-walker.org.uk/pubsebooks/pdfs/ayerLTL.pdf)"

He is considered an "ordinary language philsopher" but there's John Wisdom's "[Gods](http://faculty.gordonstate.edu/jthrasher-sneathen/Wisdom%20Gods.pdf)"

...which was developed by Anthony Flew in "[Theology and Falsification](http://www.svsu.edu/~koperski/flew.htm)"

And there's [this](http://www.markedbyteachers.com/gcse/religious-studies-philosophy-and-ethics/logical-positivism-and-the-meaninglessness-of-religious-language.html) overview.